# Android mic is sensitiveness enough to listen watch tick tack sound?

Tags: android, audio

I want to build an Android application to listen to a watch's tick-tock sound, but I am not sure that Android devices' microphones are sensitive enough to record these low frequency sounds by hands free's mic?

Does anyone know if the microphones are sensitive enough to detect that sound?

Android runs on number of devices, how can I make sure the app I am developing works with all devices?

I want to go with Samsung galaxy series first to know if it is capable to hear tick-tock?

Comment: This really depends on the hardware you're using. You probably won't get anything out of a low-end device and you might not out of a high end device either. At the very least, you should make your question specific to a particular phone.

Comment: That means i can't develop standard app which work good even with different phones of same brand like samsung?

Comment: I don't know, I'm just pointing out that you can't get a definitive answer to your question because there are so many android devices and so many different hardware variations.

Comment: There's a stack exchange for android. http://android.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depends on  a  the noise  level, the quality of the microphone  and  the  position of the microphone in the device.

If it works on one device it should  work on most devices  given  that  the  noise level is low.
Try it   with  multiple  low end an high end devices